# Meteor Hast.me app footer and header

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am currently working with the hast.me meteor project to create interactive web presentations.  I am currently trying to add a header and footer that stick to the very top and very bottom of presentation slides (in full-screen mode and edit mode).  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?  Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Show us the code of what you've got so far.

Comment: I'm using the default code as I am only making grammatical and text based changes in the editor.  The git is https://github.com/zhouzhuojie/hast.git     -   I've haven't really tried anything as I don't even know where to begin.  I'm not sure if I should add a div tag and create associates attributes in the CSS file or if I need to establish a footer and header as templates and create routes in the router file.  I am fairly new at this unfortunately.  (Also, I'm not sure how I would post all the code to all of the files in the package).